# JS: Is there a way to make a cell in a grid not clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, cell

So I'm basically making a grid where a single click is a circle and a double click is a square. However, if I go back to an already clicked box and make a single or double click, it changes the shape in it. Is there a way to make an already clicked box not clickable anymore?

[Here is my current code](https://codesandbox.io/s/72mm0yw5kx?fontsize=14)

Comment: I tried to make a variable lastClicked and I set it to 1 if clicked in both single click and double click. Then I made an if statement that checks if lastClicked is 1 and changes el class name with el.className = "noclick" from the CSS property pointer-events:none but it doesn't work? **the code is in the link, it'd be great if you took a look at it because it'll be easier to understand**

Comment: Hi, I'd like to solve your problem, but the code in your link is no longer available. Can you refresh the link?

Comment: @AndyHoffman https://codesandbox.io/s/lx1x11mv39?fontsize=14 please go ahead, the circle square click problem is solved but whenever I single click for a circle first, it doesn't add the key value pair to the map :/

Comment: Well, you've already chosen someone's answer. Is this still an active question?

Comment: I have made another question specific for this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962599/js-how-to-append-key-value-pairs-at-the-end-of-the-dictionary Thank you for willing to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

https://codesandbox.io/s/vn96m0o6l

Problem is that double click is still click. So it first triggers click handler than double click. That is why i set timeout of 200ms on click handler.

Double click handler also passes isDoubleClick flag so that handler knows what to do. And in handler based on that and class not existing yet decides which action to do. When click handler gets activated, element already has class and just ignores it.

Could be better, but will fix problem

Comment: Hey thank you very much it works!! But this leads to not registering the double click as a "1" in the dictionary. I am also trying to keep a log of shapes made with 0 being a click (single click) and square being 1 (double click).

Comment: Np, there might be problem with timeout, and adding extra flag checking might help as an improvement

Comment: Actually my bad, it does register it. I'm sorry! Thank you again for all of your help! I really appreciate it. I wish I could upvote your answer but I just joined stackoverflow haha

Answer (score 3):

I believe setting the CSS property 'pointer-events' to 'none' should work.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: How would I link that .pointer-events to the cell that was clicked once?

Comment: I don't think it would work in your solution as you are first setting clicked, than niclicked class. And both need to be unclickable.

Comment: @chriss Yes, once it is clicked, I want it to be unclickable :/ is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Erie Added bellow link with updated change. You have problem that with double click both click and dbclick gets triggered. And that gets a bit of conflict

Answer (score 1):

Just add A variable after click and use this

```
if (isClicked = 1){ 
$(this).unbind("click");
}
```

or use vanilla js like this

```
document.getElementById("myElement").onclick = function() { return false; }
```

Comment: Can you please put that more into context? Would I do it in the el.addEventListener's function?

Comment: @eerie i could not see your code as page expired but onclick is already an event.