# How to append key value pairs at the end of the dictionary?

Tags: javascript, html, css, object

I'm trying to assign 0 to every single click and 1 to every double click and have a log of the click and the position in a map. However, the keys are all sorted in ascending order even though I did not try to sort them. Is there a way to add the position key with the 1 or 0 as the value at the end while making sure all clicks register? I even tried converting the key to a string using `String(i)`.

Here is the *full* code for the project I'm working on: [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/lx1x11mv39?fontsize=14)

```js
var lastClicked;
var map = {};

var grid = clickableGrid(20, 30, function(el, row, col, i, isDoubleClick) {

  if (!isDoubleClick && !el.className) {
    el.className = "clicked";
    map[String(i)] = 0;
  } else if (isDoubleClick && !el.className) {
    el.className = "niclicked";
    map[String(i)] = 1;
  }
  console.log(map);
});

document.body.appendChild(grid);
```

Comment: I haven't read the entire code but if you're wondering about the keys: The order of keys in ES6 is numerical keys in ascending order, string keys in the order they were added, then symbols. You need to use an array if you want to keep the order of insertion http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#traversing-the-own-keys-of-an-object

Comment: Works pretty well in SO sandbox, cannot reproduce clicking problem. On codesandbox.io as well. Using  Firefox.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Yeah it started working for me too, I changed the console.log(map) to after the if statements. Thanks!

Comment: @adiga Do you mean have an array with arrays where each array would have the first index that is the position and second index which is the 1 or 0?

Comment: following @adiga comment, can you try saving log using Array.push which inserts at the end of the Array (instead of `map[String(i)] = 0`)? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: @Erie testing this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lx1x11mv39?fontsize=14) I actually sometimes gets clicks in console that are NOT put at the end. (looks like it uses numerical keys in ascending order issue, thus, losing the historic you are looking too?)

Comment: @el-teedee but can I do .push for dictionaries? I changed it to the array format after what adiga said and it works and the order is preserved. Here is the code I'm running: https://codesandbox.io/s/lx1x11mv39?fontsize=14

Comment: looks like your new sandbox works fine, having position, and type of click, which order preserved. Note, I think you should define function clickableGrid before it is called.

Comment: Is there a reason you'd prefer a dictionary? Is it for being able to access a cell's click status quickly? I don't see any trace in your code where you want to read directly by key... which is the purpose of a dictionary.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want a map and the insertion order?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone in order to evaluate what other shapes are near the current shape click. I'm trying to make a game. trincot, I don't really need a dict per say so the array thing works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the order of keys in plain objects are visited when you iterate them, is not guaranteed to be by insertion-order. Specifically, values that (when converted to number) are positive integers in the 32-bit range, get visited in numerical order.

Arrays are an alternative, as they clearly maintain insertion order when using `push`. The downside is that they do not offer the dictionary behaviour, whereby you can find the entry by (original) key.

If you really need the dictionary behaviour and, at the same time, insertion-order, then `Map` can be a solution:

```
var lastClicked;
var map = new Map; // <---

var grid = clickableGrid(20, 30, function(el, row, col, i, isDoubleClick) {

  if (!isDoubleClick && !el.className) {
    el.className = "clicked";
    map.set(i, 0);
  } else if (isDoubleClick && !el.className) {
    el.className = "niclicked";
    map.set(i, 1);
  }
  map.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key, value)); //<-- insertion order!
});

document.body.appendChild(grid);
```

You can use: `map.get(key)` to get the 0/1 value for a given key in constant time, like you would with a plain object.